# How does Python handle multiple conditions in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list

I was trying to create a list comprehension from a function that I had and I came across an unexpected behavior. Just for a better understanding, my function gets an integer and checks which of its digits divides the integer exactly:

```
# Full function
divs = list()
for i in str(number):
    digit = int(i)
    if digit > 0 and number % digit == 0:
        divs.append(digit)
return len(divs)

# List comprehension
return len([x for x in str(number) if x > 0 and number % int(x) == 0])
```

The problem is that, if I give a `1012` as an input, the full function returns `3`, which is the expected result. The list comprehension returns a `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero` instead. I understand that it is because of this condition:

```
if x > 0 and number % int(x) == 0
```

In the full function, the multiple condition is handled from the left to the right, so it is fine. In the list comprehension, I do not really know, but I was guessing that it was not handled in the same way.

Until I tried with a simpler function:

```
# Full function
positives = list()
for i in numbers:
    if i > 0 and 20 % i ==0:
        positives.append(i)
return positives

# List comprehension
return [i for i in numbers if i > 0 and 20 % i == 0]
```

Both of them worked. So I am thinking that maybe it has something to do with the `number % int(x)`? This is just curiosity on how this really works? Any ideas?

Comment: i'm surprised that you would get a `ZeroDivisionError` and not a `TypeError` for comparing x with 0, ie `str > int`

Comment: @RNar: In Py2, mismatched type comparisons don't raise exceptions (unless custom comparator code gets involved and does so on purpose). They use a fallback comparison that gets "arbitrary but consistent ordering"; the simple version of that fallback is that it's comparing the string names of each type.

Comment: ahhh, i see. py3 has an explicit error raised for it so that's why I could not replicate

Comment: Yeah. They changed it in Py3 precisely because the fallback comparison was non-intuitive and let probable errors pass silently. The main casualty from the change is that it breaks some code that, rather than filtering values added to a `list`, instead inserted `None` to indicate "no value". Sorting such a `list` moved all the `None`s to the front (which I thought was a coincidence of `None` being the only thing whose `type`, `NoneType` begins with a capital letter, making it sort before everything else; turns out `None` is actually explicitly special cased to be "smallest" in CPython).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list comprehension is different, because you compare `x > 0` without converting `x` to `int`. In Py2, mismatched types will compare in an [arbitrary and stupid but consistent way](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.10/Objects/object.c#l762), which in this case sees all `str`s (the type of `x`) as greater than all `int` (the type of `0`) meaning that the `x > 0` test is always `True` and the second test always executes (see **Footnote** below for details of this nonsense). Change the list comprehension to:

```
[x for x in str(number) if int(x) > 0 and number % int(x) == 0]
```

and it will work.

Note that you could simplify a bit further (and limit redundant work and memory consumption) by importing a Py3 version of `map` at the top of your code (`from future_builtins import map`), and using a generator expression with `sum`, instead of a list comprehension with `len`:

```
return sum(1 for i in map(int, str(number)) if i > 0 and number % i == 0)
```

That only calls `int` once per digit, and constructs no intermediate `list`.

---

**Footnote**: `0` is a numeric type, and all numeric types are "smaller" than everything except `None`, so a `str` is always greater than `0`. In non-numeric cases, it would be comparing the string type names, so `dict` < `frozenset` < `list` < `set` < `str` < `tuple`, except oops, `frozenset` and `set` compare "naturally" to each other, so you can have non-transitive relationships; `frozenset() < []` is true, `[] < set()` is true, but `frozenset() < set()` is false, because the type specific comparator gets invoked in the final version. Like I said, arbitrary and confusing; it was removed from Python 3 for a reason.

Comment: What is interesting, Python 3 warns explicitely: TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Comment: That gives you a list of strings, not of integers - add another `int` or simply iterate over `map(int, str(number))` instead.

Comment: @RomanSusi yes, this behaviour was changed in 3.x; see https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Since the OP was just checking the length, not using the `list`, the type of the values in the resulting `list` didn't matter. I did just add a better solution that avoids repeated `int`-ification and the intermediate `list` when all they wanted was a count of values passing the filter.

Comment: Thank you guys! I feel a bit stupid because I forgot the `int(x)`, but I found this topic really interesting... so I got that going for me, which is nice :P

Answer (score 0):

You should say int(x) > 0 in the list comprehension